# Clone OctoberCMS application

Tags: vagrant, octobercms

I'm currently developing an OctoberCMS website on VirtualBox using ScotchBox.

I've bought a new machine and I want to transfer my work there. I'm trying to find a way to completely/identically clone my VMbox to that PC, but to no avail, I'm still stuck with that.

Now, I'm thinking to just clone my current OctoberCMS development environment. Is there a way to clone/duplicate my OctoberCMS app to another ScotchBox? Because, I do not want to re-setup everything from the start all over again. I've already done a few things and it will be a waste of time to copy and paste them again.

What I want to happen is to clone my current OctoberCMS to another PC as if I was just working on my old PC, is it possible?

---

What I'm thinking is of course, I need to dump my database, and I'm thinking of zipping my OctoberCMS directory. But I do think that there's an *official/recommended* way of doing it?

By the way, my Box is using `folder sync`, so my actual OctoberCMS files are located on my host machine.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: It took more time to write this question than just dump a database and to tar the source code directory.

Comment: Sorry, I asked because I'm thinking that their might be other factors/parts of the application that may affect the transfer if I would just do that. E.g., the octobercms setup might have created setup/config files on the VM itself upon installation, and I might have missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it,

its just fine everything is working on `relative urls` and `relative path` so you don't need to worry about it,

> its pages are almost `flat files` so they will come with copy paste :) so no issue there.

even during setup process it just copy `zip` files from server and paste on local and `unzip` it.

1. so just take backup/dump database and setup in new machine.
2. `zip` your entire October cms and `unzip` it to new machine.
3. then edit `config/database.php` for correct `user-name` and `password`

then you are done :)

> I do same for most of the time and its working just fine trust me.

if you find any other difficulties just write comment.

Comment: Hi I have a question, so I need to install a fresh octobercms in my new machine, after which, then I will replace the whole octobercms? Or should I just copy and paste my octobercms and run something like `composer install`?

Comment: you don't need to install anything (you dont need to fire any commands) , just copy and past :)

Comment: thank you! it worked! :)